# SASS Mixin typography issue while implementing multi language

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, frontend

I am working on a react website which use sass for managing styling. So in the website I have implemented typography for english language through sass mixins.
There are different headings and bodies in the typography like heading1, heading2 , body1, body2 etc . Format of each element in typography is like

```
  @mixin body1{
      font-size:10px,
      font-weight: 700,
      letter-spacing: 1px,
      line-height:1  
  }
   @mixin body2{
      font-size:5px,
      font-weight: 400,
      letter-spacing: 1px,
      line-height:1  
    }
```

And then I include this body in my component css like :

```
   .primaryButton .text{
     @include body1;
    }
    .secondaryButton .text{
     @include body2;
    }
```

so button is single component is react , we are just changing parent class based on variation props and so its styling .

Now the issue is that I have to implement typography for different languages  like about 50 languages and I an not sure what generic approach will be best to implement .

**Note :**

1. We didn't use generic classes instead of mixin for typography because we have variation and theme for each component and for each variation and theme same element may have different font size and other properties so for different variation we load different typography elements based on component parent class.
2. Also I don't want to go in each file and then overwrite english typography based on parent class for each language as project size is too big for that and also 50 languages is also too many for that approach. And in future language can increase .

Comment: Overuse of mixins like this will greatly swell the size of your output CSS files. Remember that its just basically copy-paste since CSS is a "dumb" declarative language. And you can still have flexibility with generic css classes - you just need to do it better.

Comment: @max I can use generic class also for typography but for each component we have variation which have different style . So it will be also a bad practice  to put condition on each HTML element for generic class  . Instead of condition on each html element I put condition on parent class and then by using that class I put styling for child elements  by using mixins.

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this

Placeholders

```
%body1{
  font-size:10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height:1;
}
%body2{
  font-size:5px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height:1;
}
%body3{
  font-size:5px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height:1;
}
```

Configs

```
$langsConfig: (
  "en": (body2),
  "fr": (body1, body2),
  "cn": (body2, body3),
  "bn": (body1, body2, body3),
);
```

css generator

```
@each $lang, $placeholderList in $langsConfig {
  .#{$lang} {
    .primaryButton {
      .text {
        @each $placeholder in $placeholderList {
          @extend %#{$placeholder}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output

```
.bn .primaryButton .text, .fr .primaryButton .text {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: red;
}

.bn .primaryButton .text, .cn .primaryButton .text, .fr .primaryButton .text, .en .primaryButton .text {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: green;
}

.bn .primaryButton .text, .cn .primaryButton .text {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: yellow;
}
```

React implementation

```
export default function App() {
  const lang = "en";
  return (
    <div className={`${lang}`}>
      <div className="primaryButton">
        <h1 className="text">Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2 className="text">Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Explanation:

Placeholder: Instead of mixing use placeholder.
Config: Language name and related mixing list
Generator: it will make a loop with configs and create the css is dynamic ways

NOTE: if you want to use component based scss. Then create a scss function and pass the variables in css generator.

Here is the [Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-cloud-8n0ep?file=/src/App.js:59-349)

Let me know if it helps. It could be more dynamic if i could know the implementation on react side.